# Angular Material Style Completed Steps

Tags: css, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-material-stepper

Is there a way to style the icon of a completed step in Angular Materials stepper module?  When I complete a step it adjusts the icon to a check mark.  I'm trying to adjust the background color of the icon as well.  My code is similar to the example here with linear mode enabled: https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview

When I look in the DOM the only attribute that changes when it is completed is the 'ng-reflect-ng-switch' attribute.  I'm not sure how I can target this element in order to style it upon completion.  Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by targeting the elements attribute like this:

```
[ng-reflect-ng-switch~="done"] {
  background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: Using ng-reflect attributes for styling is a bad idea since they are for debugging purposes and are not available in production environments.